# What is proper component composition and use of props in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm struggling with this concept in vue.js..

I'm assuming that a component in Vue is an entity with some (html) representation and internal data or state. The component can then change it's internal data based on user's interaction with the template and inform the 'outer world' about its internal changes via events.

But then to put the component in context of the application as a whole most components need to receive data from the 'outer world' which would be done via props. So for a component to be useful it most often needs to change not only it's internal state but also some data it was given from the outer context - but props cannot be mutated directly. The internal data is for the internal working of the component but the real purpose of a component is to transform the data in props.

Lets say we have a component which is, via props, given an object representing a user profile for instance. The role of the component is to let the user edit their profile.
 - to avoid mutating the prop (or a subproperties of the prop), i'd add a local copy of the prop which the component could work with freely - but i'd also have to add a watch to update the local copy every time the prop gets updated by the parent via v-bind.

```js
</template>
  <input v-model="localUserProfile.name"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    userProfile: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      localUserProfile: this.userProfile
    }
  },
  watch: {
    userProfile (newVal) { this.localUserProfile = newVal }
  }
}
</script>
```

I could replace the watch with a computed property based on the given prop and let the component work over the computed property but then where to assign the edited values? Use the computed property's setter and 'emit' on changes?

Both these cases seem like a lot of extra code for a very common and repetitive task. What are some other common approaches to this? Are any of my assumptions wrong?

Comment: If you have complex en nested components that should handle state, you can check VueX that's the official global state manager for Vue. You then can mutate the things you need from within components and VueX state is reactive so the changes are reflected on all components. That way you don't have to use a lot of props and emits to updated things up or down the components hierarchy https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes vuex is probably a solution, but one which I don't really like, because of the global nature. I much more prefer having some top level component managing the state and having the data flow up and down the component tree.. but yes, vuex could be a solution

Comment: In the example given here I think using a computed property with `get` and `set`, as proposed in the question, would be the correct way to implement it. An alternative would be to split the `v-model` up into a prop/event pair but you would still end up writing about as much code. If something comes in via a prop then any changes need to go back up via `$emit`.

Comment: @raravy it's not actually global as in global variables, it's just global in the sense that it's a single source of truth, I don't see the problem on that and it's the official vue solution for your problem, nesting props bindings and emits becomes really hard to maintain really quickly

Answer (score 0):

You should not update the prop from the children component :

All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand.

In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

You can read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

If you have no other solution than updating if from the children component, it might be worth thinking about a different data flow strategy or design. [(Components Basics)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: Can you please describe some of the different data flow strategy or designs? That's actually what I'm asking for ;)

Comment: sure, I had personally faced a lot of reactivity issues that had forced me to completely redesign some applications. It’s common for an app to be organized into a tree of nested [components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Organizing-Components) where data flows from the base to the extremities. With this strategy in mind when starting a new project and with some experience, my applications started to emit less and less custom events to the parent components, eliminating a good amount of issues and improving component re-usability.